# Why is it only returning the first characteristic for BLE service?

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a scan for peripherals going for 60 seconds, in which I take the scanResult and put them in a listView adapter. Each item in listView has a button, onButtonClick, I am trying to read a list of characteristics from a service inside the adapter.

```
      button1.Click +=  (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
               {

                   string sensorId = (string)((Button)sender).Tag;
                   int index = Sensors.FindIndex(x => x.SensorId == sensorId);
                   Sensor currentSensor = Sensors[index];

                   if (currentSensor.SensorId != null)
                   {
                       BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.BluetoothService);
                       BluetoothAdapter adapter = manager.Adapter;
                       BluetoothDevice device = adapter.GetRemoteDevice(currentSensor.SensorId);

                       gattCallback.ServicesDiscoveredEvent += GattCallback_ServicesDiscoveredEventAsync;
                       gattCallback.CharacteristicReadEvent += GattCallback_CharacteristicReadEvent;
    
                   }
                });


   private void GattCallback_ServicesDiscoveredEventAsync(BluetoothGatt gatt)
        {
            service = gatt.GetService(Java.Util.UUID.FromString("0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
            foreach (var c in service.Characteristics)
            {
                gatt.ReadCharacteristic(c);
            }
                               
        }



  private void GattCallback_CharacteristicReadEvent(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, GattStatus status)
        {
            switch (status)
                {
                    case GattStatus.ConnectionCongested:
                        break;
                    case GattStatus.Failure:
                        break;
                    case GattStatus.InsufficientAuthentication:
                        break;
                    case GattStatus.InsufficientEncryption:
                        break;
                    case GattStatus.InvalidAttributeLength:
                        break;
                    case GattStatus.InvalidOffset:
                        break;
                    case GattStatus.ReadNotPermitted:
                        break;
                    case GattStatus.RequestNotSupported:
                        break;
                    case GattStatus.Success:
                    var val = BitConverter.ToString(characteristic.GetValue()).Replace("-", "");
                    Console.WriteLine("CHAR VAL : " + val);
                    break;
                    case GattStatus.WriteNotPermitted:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
           
        }
```

With the following code above, I am only seeing the result of the first characteristic in the list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to check: Are you sure the service contains more than one characteristic? have you checked using a generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Yes, it's got 5 characteristics, but only the first one is being read.

Answer (score 0):

You are only allowed to have one outstanding GATT transaction per BluetoothGatt object. You can't just issue read requests for every characteristic in a foreach loop like that. Please wait for one read to complete before you execute the next request.